# slurm high priority to jobs with lower resources

Tags: slurm

How can slurm assign high priority to jobs with lower resources?
This requires slurm tres, but with the settings, I can only get higher priority to high resources.

```
PriorityType=priority/multifactor
PriorityFlags=SMALL_RELATIVE_TO_TIME
AccountingStorageTRES=cpu,mem
PriorityWeightTRES=cpu=100,mem=1000
```

Someone have example slurm settings ?

lower CPU -> higher priority

lower memory -> higher priority

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [PriorityFavorSmall](https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm.conf.html#OPT_PriorityFavorSmall) option in the slurm.conf. Take a look at the [Priority/Multifactor](https://slurm.schedmd.com/priority_multifactor.html#jobsize) page. What you need is something like:

```
PriorityWeightJobSize=1000 #This value depends on the other weights. Choose something suitable for your config.
PriorityFavorSmall=YES
PriorityFlags=SMALL_RELATIVE_TO_TIME #If you want to take the walltime into account
```

Comment: Yes, sounds like what I'm looking for. But with "PriorityFavorSmall=YES", jobs with higher resources have still higher priority. Maybe I miss something? Slurm Service is restartet after config change.

Comment: "job size factor correlates to the number of nodes or CPUs the job has requested", there is no way to include memory?

Comment: I don't think so. https://slurm.schedmd.com/priority_multifactor.html#mfjppintro states that job size is dependent on CPUs.